# Equivalence of summations (simple)

Tags: summation, self-learning

Denote $[n]=\{1,\dotsc,n\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Consider the finite sum $\sum_{(i,j)\in A} f(x_i,x_j)$ where $A\subseteq [n]^2$. Assume that $A=\cup_{l=1}^n A_l$ is a disjoint union and $A_l=\{(l,j): (l,j)\in A\},l=1,\dotsc,n$. Can I conclude that $$\sum_{(i,j)\in A} f(x_i,x_j)=\sum_{l=1}^n\sum_{(l,j)\in A_l} f(x_i,x_j) ?$$

I think this is the case. But it is not clear to me how to argue that. Maybe I have to see this as
$$\sum_{(i,j)\in \cup_{l=1}^n A_l}f(x_i,x_j)=\sum_{(i,j)\in A_1}f(x_i,x_j)+\dotsc +\sum_{(i,j)\in A_n}f(x_i,x_j)\\ 
=\sum_{(1,j)\in A_1}f(x_i,x_j)+\dotsc +\sum_{(n,j)\in A_n}f(x_i,x_j)\\
=\sum_{l=1}^n\sum_{(l,j)\in A_l} f(x_i,x_j)$$.

What do you think?

Comment: So $n$ is the number of elements in $[n]$ and the number of sets in the partition. Do you really mean this?

Comment: Yes! Actually, $A_l=\{(l,j): (l,j)\in A\},l=1,\dotsc,n$.

Comment: @CelineHarumi: Your arguments and your derivation are sound. In case you want to argue your claim somewhat shorter, it is sufficient to take the left-most term of your argument-chain and put it into the middle of your first equation. (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the co-domain of $f$ has associative and commutative addition, then you can reorder the finite terms of the sum as you like.

Note that there seems to be a clerical error in your formulation, in

$$\sum_{l=1}^n\sum_{(\color{red}l,j)\in A_l} f(x_i,x_j)$$

the $\color{red}l$ should be replaced with an $i$.

Or maybe you started with the special case that $A_l=\{(l,j) \in A\}$, which would explain both that error as well as ajotaxte's comment.

Comment: The codomain of $f$ is the real line. You re right. Indeed, I was assuming myself your special case.